# How can I inmediately update a numeric input default value?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I will give some context first. Suppose I have a client that works in a bar. That client wants to optimize the amount of coffe they buy per working day to maximize savings. To do so, the client needs to provide some initial inputs, such as the size of the bar, the number of clients per week and the current amount of coffe they buy per working day. Once it has provided all the necessary information to the app, there is an "Optimize" button that triggers some calculations and returns 6 new optimized values. Once these six values are computed, they are rendered in some boxes, plots are also rendered and the savings between the initial bought amounts and the optimized ones are shown. However, the user needs to have the option to modify those proposed values, and if he does so, the graphics and the savings need to be recalculated and shown.

My app is divided into global.R, ui.R and server.R files and I will now provide a minimal reproducible example of them.

```
# global.R

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)

optimize_coffee <- function(d1) {
    return (d1 + 1)
}
```

Please note that the provided optimize_coffe function is just an oversimplification. The real function takes into account different parameters and it does much more complex and slower calculations.

Now I will provide my UI code just in case anyone wants to reproduce this in their computer, however I believe it is not relevant to the problem.

```
# ui.R

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    navbarPage(
        header = tagList(
            useShinydashboard()
        ),
        collapsible = TRUE,
        HTML('<a>Coffee optimization</a>'), # nolint
        id = "nav",
        windowTitle = "Coffee optimization",
        tabPanel(
            "Principal",
            fluidRow(
                column(
                    3,
                    fluidRow(
                        sidebarPanel(
                            h3("Coffee optimization"),
                            width = 12,
                            h4("Coffe bought per day:"),
                            fluidRow(
                                column(
                                    4,
                                    numericInput("d1_coffeebought", label = "D1", value = 0, min = 0)
                                )
                            ),

                            actionButton("optimize", label = "Optimize", class = "btn-primary", width = "100%"),
                        )
                    )
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    width = 9,
                    fluidRow(
                        column(
                            3,
                            infoBoxOutput("savings_box", width = 12)
                        ),
                        column(
                            9,
                            fluidRow(
                                tags$div(
                                    HTML("<p>Optimized coffees</p>")
                                ),
                                column(
                                    2,
                                    numericInput(inputId = "optimized_cofeesd1", label = "D1", value = "-", min = 0, max = 10000, step = .1)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    fluidRow(
                        column(6, plotOutput("savings_graphicd1"))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The real UI has more inputs but they do not affect to the problem I am presenting.

```
# server.R

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # A lot of other functionalities
    output$savings_box <- renderInfoBox({
        infoBox(
            value = "No offer",
            title = "Savings",
            width = 12,
            icon = icon("wallet")
        )
    })

    output$savings_graphicd1 <- renderPlot(NULL)

    # A lot of other functionalities

    observeEvent(input$optimize,
        {
            optimized_coffees <- optimize_coffee(input$d1_coffeebought
            )

            user_optimized_coffees <- reactive({
                if (is.na(input$optimized_cofeesd1)) {
                    optimized_coffees
                } else {
                    c(
                        input$optimized_cofeesd1
                    )
                }
            })

            # Trying to update the numericInput value with the optimized coffees,
            # however, this only updates when all the plots are rendered.
            updateNumericInput(session = session, inputId = "optimized_cofeesd1", value = round(optimized_coffees, 1))

            computed_savings <- reactive({
                if (!is.null(user_optimized_coffees())) {
                    sum(user_optimized_coffees())
                }
            })

            output$savings_box <- renderInfoBox({
                infoBox(
                    value = computed_savings(),
                    title = "Savings",
                    width = 12,
                    icon = icon("wallet")
                )
            })
            # Render the resultant plots
        }
    )
}
```

This is my current approach. I set the boxes to be numericInputs with empty initial values. After that I compute the optimized values for those boxes and I would ideally like the numericInputs to show the new optimized values inmediately, as would happen when a default value for the numericInputs is set.

However, as of today, 17 March 2023, the updateNumericInput just sends the message to client once all the objects have been rendered, what causes the computed_savings (and thus the savings_box) and the plots to be rendered twice in the first execution. This is quite annoying as the user sees the plots once but inmediately after this, they are deleted to be rendered once again, process that takes around 5 seconds.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I do not really need the boxes to be numericInputs, I just need a box which values can be modifiable but I have not found anything better. Appart from that, I also cannot add a refresh button.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't nest your reactives.  That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How can I solve it?

Comment: Your example is far from minimal (200+ lines, with many features and packages not relevant to the question) so I don't intend to explore in detail.  However, R's normal scoping rules apply to Shiny, so reactives you defione, for example, *inside* `observeEvent(input$optimize, ...)` are not available to functions and processes elsewhere, one of which is the daemon that manages Shiny reactivity.  Also, you say you want to update the *labels* of your `numericInput`s to update, yet you do not attempt to modify labels of any widget in your code nor explain how you want them to be updated.

Comment: I have reedited the question to reduce the lines of code and add some clarifications, sorry for that, it is my first question here. Regarding the scoping of reactives, all the reactives I use are defined and used just inside the same `observeEvent(input$optimize, ...)`. What I want in the `numericInput` is to show as a default value the new optimized ones. I try to do that by using the `updateNumericInput` function, but that function only updates the values once every output is rendered, and I need it to work before that. Once again, sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

After some days of working, I have found a workaround for my situation. At the beginning, every trigger was put inside the same observeEvent, what caused the updateNumericInput to just work once all the objects inside that observeEvent were rendered and thus leading to the problem of everything loading twice.

To solve that I have just divided the code into different observeEvents, so that the one that contains the updateNumericInput does not contain any output rendering and works when I want it to work.

The global.R and the ui.R files do not have any modification. The server.R file is now as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # A lot of other functionalities
    output$savings_box <- renderInfoBox({
        infoBox(
            value = "No offer",
            title = "Savings",
            width = 12,
            icon = icon("wallet")
        )
    })

    output$savings_graphicd1 <- renderPlot(NULL)

    # A lot of other functionalities

    observeEvent(input$optimize,
        {

            optimized_coffees <- optimize_coffee(input$d1_coffeebought)


            updateNumericInput(session, "optimized_coffeesd1", value = optimized_coffees)



        }
    )

    observeEvent(req(!is.na(input$optimized_coffeesd1)), 
    # The req just returns a value if the condition inside is TRUE, thus, the observeEvent is only triggered if the input is not NA
    # The real observeEvent checks for a list of optimized_coffesd1..optimized_coffeesd6, but I'm just using d1 for the example
        {
            user_optimized_coffees <- reactive({
                input$optimized_coffeesd1
            })

            computed_savings <- reactive({
                sum(user_optimized_coffees())
            })

            output$savings_box <- renderInfoBox({
                infoBox(
                    value = computed_savings(),
                    title = "Savings",
                    width = 12,
                    icon = icon("wallet")
                )
            })

        }
    )

    observeEvent(req(!is.na(input$optimized_coffeesd1)),
        {
        
            output$savings_graphicd1 <- renderPlot({
                plot(1:10, 1:10)
            })

        }
    )
    # The real example has one observeEvent per optimized_coffeesd1..optimized_coffeesd6 and each of them renders
    # the plot of the optimized coffees
}
```

This has an aditional advantage, unlike the first version, a change in an optimized coffee just triggers the reload of the directly associated plot.

Hope this helps for anyone who passes by!